# How to do web-scraping with python on pages with dynamic content?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to do web scraping on flight pages to compare prices for a specific month on the airlines, at the moment I have this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36')


# Dates
dates = ['2023-04-01', '2023-04-02', '2023-04-03', '2023-04-04', '2023-04-05', '2023-04-06', '2023-04-07', '2023-04-08', '2023-04-09', '2023-04-10', '2023-04-11', '2023-04-12', '2023-04-13', '2023-04-14', '2023-04-15', '2023-04-16', '2023-04-17', '2023-04-18', '2023-04-19', '2023-04-20', '2023-04-21', '2023-04-22', '2023-04-23', '2023-04-24', '2023-04-25', '2023-04-26', '2023-04-27', '2023-04-28', '2023-04-29', '2023-04-30']
prices = {}

for date in dates:

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    url = f'https://www.latamairlines.com/co/es/ofertas-vuelos?origin=BOG&inbound=null&outbound={date}T17%3A00%3A00.000Z&destination=BGA&adt=1&chd=0&inf=0&trip=OW&cabin=Economy&redemption=false&sort=RECOMMENDED'
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source
    driver.quit()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    spans = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'display-currencystyle__CurrencyAmount-sc__sc-19mlo29-2 fMjBKP'})
    prices[date] = []
    for span in spans:
        texto = span.text.strip() 
        if texto not in prices[date]:
            prices[date].append(texto)

print(prices)
```

The idea is to go through all the pages for all the dates of the month, since for each date the URL changes. My idea was to apply this implementation to more web pages (changing the url and the search html tags accordingly). However, I have come across pages like: https://www.easyfly.com.co/ in which when I configure a date and destination, I do not get a URL with the parameters, but rather an application that I suppose loads dynamically:

[image]

What should be done in these cases? To which URL should I make the request? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a site that changes URL based on date?

Comment: Yes, the page of the code example changes according to the date:: https://www.latamairlines.com/co/es/ofertas-vuelos?origin=BOG&inbound=null&outbound=2023-04-01T17%3A00%3A00.000Z&destination=MDE&adt=1&chd=0&inf=0&trip=OW&cabin=Economy&redemption=false&sort=RECOMMENDED

Comment: As you've already noticed, there is no specific URL you can go to. You *could* watch [network logs](https://support.happyfox.com/kb/article/882-accessing-the-browser-console-and-network-logs/) as you click on various dates and try to replicate those requests; but since you're already using selenium, I think it would be easier to just click on the necessary elements to load that page - section 3-5 of [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) explain about locating and interacting with elements and how to wait for them to load